# Trying to get email activation to work, but it fails

Tags: django, django-email

Trying to get this tutorial to work in my app:
https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef

The 'uid' fails whether or not I include the .decode().

```
message = render_to_string('premium/activation_email.html', {'user':user,

 'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
 #this fails both with the .decode() and without
 'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)).decode(),
            })
mail_subject = 'Activate your membership account.'
send_mail(mail_subject, message,'info@mysite.com', [request.user.email])
```

These are the two errors:

```
Reverse for 'activate' not found. 'activate' is not a valid view function or pattern name
```

Then if I add .decode():

```
str object has no attribute decode()
```

here is my urls.py with the activate tag:

```
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, 'activate'),
```

my activate view is exactly the same as the one in the tutorial

Comment: Can you show full traceback for the first error please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Django >2.2`, [urlsafe_base64_encode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.http.urlsafe_base64_encode) will return string instead of bytestring so you don't have to call `.decode()` after `urlsafe_base64_encode` anymore.

> Changed in Django 2.2:
>   In older versions, it returns a bytestring instead of a string.

Follow the guideline which you embedded on your question, the issue `Reverse for 'activate' not found` comes from this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

There are 2 cases that might lead to this issue:

1. Your path:

```py
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, 'activate'),
```

you should named your view by this:

```py
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

2. If your view is stay on site level (inside django application urls, not in ROOT_URLS) then you might need to add `app_name = 'your_app_name'` on top of your `urlpatterns` inside `urls.py`. And then inside your mail template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},
Please click on the link to confirm your registration,
http://{{ domain }}{% url 'your_app_name:activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Hope that helps!